# create groupby based on label of a column in python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, rows, frequency

I have a large dataframe which is similar like this:

```
id        price             status
1           23               none
2           23               none
3           34               none
4           32               none
5           31               none
6           37               none
7           20               none
8           29               none
9           21               none
10          22               done
```

and I want to make a groupby based on the status. I want to make a group where the situation like this:
every time the status is done, it will be one group.

So far, what I have done is making a group based on the index:

```
grouper = df.groupby(df.index // 10)
```

but then I realize that the status is written done randomly and not always every 10 rows.

How can I make it in python? Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare `done` values and cretae groups by cumulative sum from back by `iloc[::-1]`, last add another `iloc[::-1]` for original order of column:

```
g = df['status'].eq('done').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
grouper = df.groupby(g, sort=False)
```

**Sample**:

```
#chnaged data for more groups   
print (df)
   id  price status
0   1     23   none
1   2     23   done
2   3     34   none
3   4     32   none
4   5     31   done
5   6     37   none
6   7     20   none
7   8     29   none
8   9     21   none
9  10     22   done

g = df['status'].eq('done').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
print (g)
0    3
1    3
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: status, dtype: int32
```

---

```
grouper = df.groupby(g, sort=False)

for name, df in grouper:
    print (df)

   id  price status
0   1     23   none
1   2     23   done
   id  price status
2   3     34   none
3   4     32   none
4   5     31   done
   id  price status
5   6     37   none
6   7     20   none
7   8     29   none
8   9     21   none
9  10     22   done
```